# Access BigQuery table in Dash App deployed on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, plotly-dash

I am deploying a Plotly Dash app on Google App Engine but meet some difficulties. The data source to be queried in the dashboard is a Bigquery table, whose content is changing. I hope that the data in the App can always be the latest.

What I tried is at the beginning of the main.py code, I read in the table from Bigquery by Bigquery Python API, but after the App being deployed onto GAE, I found the data was fixed; even I deleted the Bigquery table, the App was not affected. May I know what is the correct way to get data from BigQuery to App Engine? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How to connect to BigQuery from GAE using Python might be a bit more of a task than a single question can answer, but here are some hints:

- Everything Google Cloud can (in my opinion) be best understood through [the repositories on Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform). For instance, the python docs samples contain several examples, out of which I think the client example is probably the easiest and most basic. [Bigquery Python Samples are here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/7e066d1ed290eaa16a25d177ca1c82acb724c0bf/bigquery). That will basically answer your question, except for a few gotchas I will mention.
- You will of course need to [download the client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) to do development on a local environment. That is straightforward, but if something seems not to be working make sure you have enabled the [API service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) for your project--that can be a little confusing.
- Something that is *critically important* to remember is that your GAE app will not be able to easily communicate with BigQuery if it is in a different region, and, in fact, *once you set up a GAE app you cannot move or delete it!* So, do pay attention to what you are doing as you set up, and if you have a locations mismatch you will need to migrate your BQ instance to the matching location.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I can query BQ using Python. The problem is that I am not sure how to correctly connect to BQ in GAE. If I read in the BQ table at the beginning of the GAE codes, but it looks that it's a one-off read-in, and the data in the GAE will not change when the BQ table changes. Do I need to activate GAE cron jobs? I am new to GAE and I am confused here. Thank you.

Comment: From what environment are you currently able to query BQ? I might be a little confused because you are working with Plotly, but querying BQ is generally the same as querying a standard SQL database like MySQL or Postgres. Again, the setup guides I listed above for connecting to BigQuery from GAE really will work. I'm not sure what issue or step you are running into that is failing.

Are you hoping to update a plotly chart every time the data in BQ changes? In that case, you might be hoping for a trigger, which BigQuery does *not* have. In that case a GAE cron would be a possibility.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I am using Python3 to do the BQ query and write Dash App (then the App is deployed to GAE using Python3 standard runtime). What I tried to do is exactly to have the data shown by Plotly updated when BQ changes. I succeeded in reading BQ data in the App, but the data read in won't change when BQ changes. I got stuck there.

Comment: We are migrating away from the original question, but this seems very much like a Dash question similar to the discussion here: https://community.plotly.com/t/solved-updating-server-side-app-data-on-a-schedule/6612